# Tkinter GUI stuck till end of the task when pressing a button

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

When I press the "start program" button, it starts a 5 second task and blocks the GUI.
As i understand, I need to use Threading so each button will work independently from the GUI.
I've been stuck for almost a month already, can someone show me how can execute `def start_Button(self)`: function using threading?

```
from tkinter import *
import time


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        quitButton = Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        startButton = Button(self, text="Start Program", command=self.start_Button)

        quitButton.grid(row=0,column=0)
        startButton.grid(row=0, column=2)

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def start_Button(self):
        print('Program is starting')
        for i in range (5):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x50")
app = Window(root)
root.title("My Program")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of important questions to ask before you jump into threading for the first time, but by and large the most important question is "how do I want to communicate between my threads?" In your minimal example you don't require any communication at all, however in your real code `start_Button` may be doing some Work and returning data back to the GUI. If that's the case, you have more work to do. Please clarify that as a comment if that's the case.

For the minimal example, it's actually quite easy.

```
class Window(tkinter.Frame):
    # the rest of your GUI class as written, but change...

    def start_Button(self):
        def f():
            # this is the actual function to run
            print('Program is starting')
            for i in range (5):
                print(i)
                time.sleep(1)
        t = threading.Thread(target=f)
        t.start()
```

Comment: i tried such a solution for a long time already, but couldn't place the threading module in the right place, now that you showed me it makes sense! i know using threading is tricky and and might interferring, this is not the case in my program (for now..). thanks!